# Tengo un problema en Angular, En la línea que está comentada el error, no me obtiene el valor almacenado en el localStorage

Tags: angular

El problema es que no me rescata el valor almacenado en `localStorage` en Angular.
En la línea que tengo comentado `//AQUI EL ERROR`, se supone que debería obtener el valor del `localStorage` que está almacenado como `"currentPeriodo"`, pero no lo recupera.
Ya le he intentado creando una variable local y asignando a `this.periodo` pero no se soluciona. Puse el `console.log` para verificar.

```
  obtenerDatosUsuario(){
    var id:Number;
    id = Number(localStorage.getItem("accessToken"));
    this.periodo=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentPeriodo")); //AQUI EL ERROR
    console.log("Toquen de periodo ingresado..."+JSON.stringify(this.periodo)); 
    this.dataService.obtenerDatosUsuarioId(id).subscribe((usuarios:UsuarioTabla)=>(this.usuario=usuarios));
  }
```

¿Alguien ha tenido este problema? Me he pasado horas buscando solucionar y nada.

Saludos.

Comment: Ese Spanglish me chirría. ¿No será que guardaste el valor usando como clave "currentPeriod"?. Puedes comprobarlo usando `console.log(localStorage)`

Comment: Puedes compartir el código de como almacenas en el localStorage ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  getPeriodoActual():any{
    let periodo = localStorage.getItem("currentPeriodo");
    if(isNullOrUndefined(periodo)){
      let per:any = JSON.parse(periodo);
      return per;
    }else{
      return null;
    }

  }
```

Comment: Gracias Pablo Lozano, tengo que mejorar en mantener en manejar el idioma en la codificación. Ahí te comparto el código donde almaceno en el localStorage...

Comment: Hola @José. Bienvenido a **Stack Overflow**. Te invito realizar un [tour] para que conozca cómo funciona el sitio y ganes tu primera medalla. Por otra parte, también puede consultar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) o leer todo sobre «[respondiendo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answering)»